# An exception throwed by eclipse when do the new gwt project

Tags: gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I am newly to GWT and I started to learn it through gwt2.4. Firstly, I installed the eclipse plugin, after that, I saw the icon in the toolbar of the eclipse.

[image]

**When I click the New Web Application Project, it reported an Exception. The detailed stack-trace is below.**

eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

Error
Mon Jan 21 17:18:28 CST 2013
Unhandled event loop exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/platform/shared/ui/IPixelConverter
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.actions.NewWebAppToolbarHandler.execute(NewWebAppToolbarHandler.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.shared.ui.IPixelConverter
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more

I have no idea How it happens, I tried two methods for installing the gwt plugin. One is to use the link file and the other is to put the corresponding file into the plugins and features directory. But the same exception is reported.

Why the class cannot be founded, I have searched in the plugins directory and found this class in the jar called **com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.shared_3.1.3.v201212122040-rel-r37.jar**.

Who can help, thank you very much!!

Comment: Happens to me also .i re-installed to make it work...all the best .

Comment: I re-installed it also, but it didn't work. How did you re-installed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wipe out your eclipse installation and workspace. Download the eclipse zip file and start over.

Do not use Eclipse's uninstall plugin feature.

Answer (score 0):

I haved same problem above, now it seams the problem is solved.

My Problem is:
"Unhandled event loop exception"
Error An error has occurred. See error log for more details. com/google/gdt/eclipse/platform/shared/ui/IPixelConverter.

Resolution:
You need Install or reinstall
"Jetty-9 Bundles Composite Repository" - http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x
Checklist only: Jetty - Bundles: all the jetty bundles.
Restart the eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I installed the wrong Google plug-in version for my version of Eclipse, i.e. I followed the Google documentation and installed the 3.7 plug-in but my Eclipse was version 4.3.

It was simple to fix: remove the 3.7 plu-ing URL from Available Software Sites and add the appropriate one for my Eclipse version (in this case 4.3 - https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3).